# Download file via Spring Web

Tags: java, spring, file, download

Currently, this is my code in the controller to return a XLS file for download:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/export-data/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity exportAllData() {
        ResponseEntity respEntity = null;
        SheetDownload sheetDownload = new SheetDownload();

        try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream result = sheetDownload.createMentoringSheet();

            HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();

            byte[] out = result.toByteArray();

            responseHeaders.add("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=export-data.xlsx");
            responseHeaders.add("Content-Type", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");

            respEntity = new ResponseEntity(out, responseHeaders,HttpStatus.OK);
        }catch(Exception e){
            respEntity = new ResponseEntity ("File Not Found", HttpStatus.OK);
        }

        return respEntity;
}
```

When I go to the "network" in Chrome, all I see in the response is:
[image]

So, there's no trigger to browser download, for example. The goal is to return the file to be downloaded in the proper format (XLSX).

Can someone help me?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you can try `"Content-disposition", "inline; filename=\"export-data.xlsx\""`

Comment: I tried and this gives me this error: `HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No converter found for return value of type: class java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream`. Any ideas?